# JQuery Filter not filtering all records

Tags: jquery, filter

I am using j query filter in my code to search the records.My records consist of employee information.There are 12 pages of records.

Its working fine on the current page but if you search a record that is on page 2nd,then it does not search it.I am using the following code to search the records,

```
 (function ($) {

        $('#search').keyup(function () {

            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();

            $('.searchable tr.gradeX').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());

            }).show();



        })

    }(jQuery));
```

Html Structure,Showing just one record for demo;

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="datatable-editable">

    <thead>

        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Dept</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th style="min-width: 80px;">Action</th>
            </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody class="searchable">

        <tr class="gradeX">

            <td>Name</td>
            <td>IT</td>
            <td>USD 1200</td>
            <td>USD 1200</td>

            <td class="actions">

                <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>

                <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

            </td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you create pages? all you pages always in html? or you add current page if needed? can you provide working sample that reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Grundy, I am using php to get records from database.Using table to show records.

Comment: If it's not rendered (page 2 is not render with PHP) you can't find anything. You have two options: or make the pagination with javascript, or search in PHP instead of javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do with javascript if you are using PHP for pagination.
But get some idea like send the text entered to backend(not on keyup of every character, but for character length more than three) and get filtered json data from backend and rebind table again.